# Does Javascript allocate 32 bits of memory for variables with an undefined value?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following function signature:

```
function test(varible1, varible2) {}
```

When I call it I pass only one parameter:

```
test(5);
```

So within `test` function the `variable2` still be created but will have value of `undefined`. I'm wondering if js engine still allocates 32 bit in the memory for that variable?

Comment: JS arrays are sparse, and the argument array of a function call is some sort of array. So probably not.

Comment: To know definitively you'll need someone who's familiar with the internals of an ECMAScript implementation because the spec it's self isn't super clear on the subject (or you'll need to test it your self). What I can say is that any variable, pre-defined or not, with no value will be `undefined` - so my guess is no, they don't.

Comment: Which JS engine? There are lots. This is an implementation detail, not something determined by the specification.

Comment: @Quentin, V8 for example. Can you say anything about one that you know?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the size of undefined and I'm sure it varies with engine, but I **assume** that the **best** case is 32 bits. The variable exists, so it needs a value to even know it's undefined. That value is very likely a pointer which will be 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: My first guess was 32 on 32 systems, 64 on 64 systems. But AFAIK there's no reason it would not allocate space, even if the value is undefined.